# How can I select only the nth child of an class in JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hey there I wrote a small JS to flip elements when I am reaching a specific div, that works fine. I just want to flip one of the elements but I am trying to avoid giving that element and extra `id` or `class` in the markup since it's cms based content.

How can I tell JS to just apply it on the 8th element, for example?

JavaScript:

```
function flip_scroll() {
      var window_top = $(window).scrollTop();
      var Services = $('.c-services').offset().top;
      if (window_top > Services)
      $(".c-services__item").addClass("applyflip");
    else
      $(".c-services__item").removeClass("applyflip");
  }
     $(function() {
      $(window).scroll(flip_scroll);
      flip_scroll();

});
```

Comment: Have you looked at https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/ and https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/ ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: i will check it out and post the solution as i figured it out ..thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jQuery's [nth-child-selector](https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/)

Answer (score 0):

I just had too lok in the docs as @nickroz pointed out, thanks :-)

https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/

```
 function flip_scroll() {
          var window_top = $(window).scrollTop();
          var Services = $('.c-services').offset().top;
          if (window_top > Services)
          $(".c-services__item:nth-child(8)").addClass("applyflip");
        else
          $(".c-services__item:nth-child(8)").removeClass("applyflip");
      }
         $(function() {
          $(window).scroll(flip_scroll);
          flip_scroll();

    });
```